# Ковариантность возвращаемых типов

Tags: java

В книге Thinking in Java (Bruce Eckel) есть такой код:
Собственно интересует место с комментарием //Covariant return. Откуда тут ковариантность вообще?

```
//: interfaces/interfaceprocessor/Processor.java 
package interfaces.interfaceprocessor;

public interface Processor { 
  String name(); 
  Object process(Object input); 
} ///:~

//: interfaces/interfaceprocessor/Apply.java 
package interfaces.interfaceprocessor; 
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

public class Apply { 
  public static void process(Processor p, Object s) { 
    print("Using Processor " + p.name()); 
    print(p.process(s)); 
  } 
} ///:~

//: interfaces/interfaceprocessor/StringProcessor.java 
package interfaces.interfaceprocessor; 
import java.util.*;

public abstract class StringProcessor implements Processor{ 
  public String name() { 
    return getClass().getSimpleName(); 
  } 
  public abstract String process(Object input); 
  public static String s = 
    "If she weighs the same as a duck, she’s made of wood"; 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Apply.process(new Upcase(), s); 
    Apply.process(new Downcase(), s); 
    Apply.process(new Splitter(), s); 
  } 
}

class Upcase extends StringProcessor { 
  public String process(Object input) { **// Covariant return** 
    return ((String)input).toUpperCase(); 
  } 
}

class Downcase extends StringProcessor { 
  public String process(Object input) { 
    return ((String)input).toLowerCase(); 
  } 
}

class Splitter extends StringProcessor { 
  public String process(Object input) { 
    return Arrays.toString(((String)input).split(" ")); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идея очень простая: вы имплементируете метод `Object process(Object input)` интерфейса `Processor` методом `String process(Object input)`.

Где *на самом деле* находится метод — в абстрактном классе `StringProcessor` или в его реализации `Upcase` — в принципе не так важно, и является скорее теоретическим вопросом. Главное тут то, что тип возвращаемого значения является подтипом требуемого интерфейсом типа.

Comment: А, точно, не заметил. Я следил за типом возвращаемого значения с абстрактного класса StringProcessor, а там уже был String. Вот я и подумал какая же тут ковариантность. Но тогда комментарий о ковариантности может быть правильней было бы уже в классе StringProcessor написать, хоть там метод process и абстрактный?
Ну да ладно, это уже не столь важно.
Спасибо)

Comment: @bayah: пожалуйста!